# Bayesian posterior after dropping some information

Tags: bayesian, posterior

**Problem setup**
I have a data set $\mathcal D = \{(x_1, y_1), \dotsc, (x_n, y_n)\}$ and I would like to estimate parameter $\theta$ in the Bayesian way. I know that the Bayesian network for this model is
$$Y \leftarrow \theta \to X$$
and the distribution $P(X\mid \theta)$ is known and easy to calculate. On the other hand, $P(Y\mid \theta)$ is intractable.

Hence, it is impossible to model "the proper" Bayesian posterior
$$P(\theta \mid \mathcal D) \propto P(\mathcal D \mid \theta  ) P(\theta),$$

but it is easy to marginalize out variable $Y$ obtaining a posterior
$$P(\theta\mid \mathcal D_X) \propto P(\mathcal D_X \mid \theta  ) P(\theta),$$
where $\mathcal D_X = \{x_1, \dotsc, x_n\}$. This corresponds to replacing the original Bayesian network with a simpler model $\theta \to X$.

**The question** I wonder if marginalizing out $Y$ is a proper thing to do in this case, as I am ignoring some known information. Is replacing the original (complete, but intractable) with a simpler one common in Bayesian statistics? Can I still call $P(\theta\mid \mathcal D_X)$ the posterior?

I would be grateful for any opinions. (Or literature suggestions, so I can read more on this topic, if this question is trivial).

Comment: How do you distinguish "$P( Y \vert \theta)$ is intractable" from "I don't have a model for $P(Y \vert \theta)$"?  In what manner is it intractable?

Comment: Thank you for your question :) I meant that I didn't have a model for $P(Y\mid \theta)$. (In principle, I could train a machine learning model trying to approximate $P(Y\mid \theta)$ on some additional – and _very_ scarce – data I have, but this model won't be reasonable at all).

Comment: In practice, you never incorporate all potentially useful information into an inference.  It sounds like it's just that you've identified $Y$ as a potentially useful source of information on $\theta$.  What you want to do with this information depends on exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: The Bayesian analysis is correct in being conditional on the observed $x_i$'s. If the model for $Y$ is unavailable and if the conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y$ is also unavailable, ignoring $Y$ is the best you can do.

Comment: Thank you Dave and Xi'an for the comments! The bit that especially brought my attention is "if the conditional distribution of X given Y is also unavailable, ...". Assuming I had the distribution $P(X\mid Y)$, how could I incorporate this knowledge, without trying to learn $P(Y\mid \theta)$?

Comment: Using $p(x_i|\theta,y_i)$ instead of $p(x_i|\theta)$ in the likelihood improves the inference in that there is more information about $\theta$ in the former than in the later.

Comment: Thank you! I may have overlooked something, but my understanding is that from the assumption encoded in the Bayesian network, $p(x_i, y_i \mid \theta) = p(x_i\mid \theta) p(y_i\mid \theta)$, it follows that $p(x_i\mid \theta, y_i) = p(x_i\mid \theta)$.